# Next.js and React: Cannot read property 'UseDebugValue' of null

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

I googled this message but didn't find solution to it. The error occurs when I try to access my dynamic route:
[image]

from react component:

```
function MeetupItem(props) {
const router = useRouter()

const showDetailsHandler = () => {
    router.push('/' + props.id);
}

  return (
    <li className={classes.item}>
      <Card>
        <div className={classes.image}>
          <img src={props.image} alt={props.title} />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.content}>
          <h3>{props.title}</h3>
          <address>{props.address}</address>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <button onClick={showDetailsHandler}>Show Details</button>
        </div>
      </Card>
    </li>
  );
}

export default MeetupItem;
```

meetUpId I receive from mongoDB but IMO it's nothing wrong here. Stack trace of an error is:
[image]

Where to start? What's useDebugValue? Something wrong with styledComponents?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors on a different case and they were solved by installing the latest node js version. I would try doing that if you haven't already. Hope that helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33275614)

Comment: @keikai I believe it does provide an answer to the question "Where to start".